# Java printer status doesn't work

Tags: java, printing

I have an USB printer and I saw that I can not know if my printer job was correctly printed because the method JobTransferComplete is invoked when job arrives to the printer spool and not to the printer. If I switch off the printer the JVM continues to print without any notification. Am I right?